# ArcPy replaceDataSource to ArcSDE raster catalog error?

Tags: arcpy, layers, raster-catalog

I'm trying to re-path a multitude of rasters currently the workspace is a folder, the intended workspace is a raster catalog in an SDE database - using the replaceDataSource method I'm getting the error as below. Does anyone know if this method can't output as a Raster Catalog or what the actual problem may be?

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Folder\MyLayer.lyr")
lyr.replaceDataSource(r"pathToSDEConnectionFile.sde","SDE_WORKSPACE","rasterCatalogName", True)
```

> Runtime error : Layer: Unexpected error

Answer (score 3):

The second argument is the type of the *new* dataset. I don't think a raster catalog is an SDE_WORKSPACE even if stored via ArcSDE; Only database Connections are.

Try using "RASTER_WORKSPACE" for your keyword.